# Unknown error generating App-Specific Shared Secret

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, shared-secret

I am working on setting up remote receipt validation for IAP and I need to generate an App-Specific Shared Secret. My account has admin privileges, however, when I click to generate the secret I get the error `There was a problem retrieving the data for this page. Please try again.`

This error is pretty useless and does not tell me how to fix the issue. I have reached out to Apple Developer support but have not gotten a response back. If anyone has had similar issues any help would be great!

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @AnuragSharma I was not able to find a solution. The workaround that I used was to have the admin of the developer account generate the App-Specific Shared Secret.

Comment: In my case, the Account holder did not face this error while adding the price for In-app purchase.